# Seaborn plotting histogram and lineplot on the same figure with 2 y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

'''
I would like to generate a single plot showing both a histogram and a lineplot. The histogram and the lineplot have the same x-axis but different y-axis. From my search on Stackoverflow, I came up with the approach below.

1. The issue is that the lineplot is not going all the way to the end of the x-axis. If I comment out the barplot, then I get the lineplot as expected.
2. the other issue is that plt.xticks(rotation=60) is not rotation the number on the x-axis
   I'm not sure what is wrong when trying to make the 2 plots and how to solve the issue. Thank you in advance for helping me out.

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

myDict = {'Bin': {0: -1.0,
  1: -0.9,
  2: -0.8,
  3: -0.7,
  4: -0.6,
  5: -0.5,
  6: -0.4,
  7: -0.3,
  8: -0.2,
  9: -0.1,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.1,
  12: 0.2,
  13: 0.3,
  14: 0.4,
  15: 0.5,
  16: 0.6,
  17: 0.7,
  18: 0.8,
  19: 0.9,
  20: 1.0},
 'Frequency': {0: 51,
  1: 4,
  2: 13,
  3: 39,
  4: 52,
  5: 56,
  6: 75,
  7: 71,
  8: 81,
  9: 80,
  10: 34,
  11: 33,
  12: 28,
  13: 23,
  14: 14,
  15: 10,
  16: 11,
  17: 5,
  18: 3,
  19: 3,
  20: 0},
 'Cumulative': {0: 0.074344023,
  1: 0.080174927,
  2: 0.09912536400000001,
  3: 0.155976676,
  4: 0.231778426,
  5: 0.313411079,
  6: 0.422740525,
  7: 0.526239067,
  8: 0.644314869,
  9: 0.760932945,
  10: 0.810495627,
  11: 0.858600583,
  12: 0.89941691,
  13: 0.932944606,
  14: 0.95335277,
  15: 0.967930029,
  16: 0.983965015,
  17: 0.991253644,
  18: 0.9956268220000001,
  19: 1.0,
  20: 1.0}}

myDF = pd.DataFrame(myDataDict)
fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(x='Bin',y='Frequency',data=data_up,color='blue',ax=ax1)
sns.lineplot(x='Bin',y='Cumulative',data=data_up,marker='s',color='orange',ax=ax2)
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: plot to improve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can plot against the index and manually relabel:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# changes here
sns.barplot(x=myDF.index,y='Frequency',data=myDF,color='blue',ax=ax1)
sns.lineplot(x=myDF.index,y='Cumulative',data=myDF,marker='s',color='orange',ax=ax2)

# and here
plt.xticks(myDF.index, myDF.Bin, rotation=60)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update**: Actually , you need only change the `lineplot` command:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(x='Bin',y='Frequency',data=myDF,color='blue',ax=ax1)

# only change this line
sns.lineplot(x=myDF.index, y='Cumulative',data=myDF,marker='s',color='orange',ax=ax2)

plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.show()
```

and also get the same output.

Comment: How to add legend to this plot? legend = ['Frequencey', 'Cumulative']